# Spark 1.5.2: Grouping DataFrame Rows over a Time Range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `df` with the following schema:

```
ts: TimestampType 
key: int 
val: int
```

The `df` is sorted in ascending order of `ts`. Starting with row(0), I would like to group the dataframe within certain time intervals.

For example, if I say `df.filter(row(0).ts + expr(INTERVAL 24 HOUR)).collect()`, it should return all the rows within the 24 hr time window of row(0).

Is there a way to achieve the above within Spark DF context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it is relatively simple task. All you need is basic arithmetics on UNIX timestamps. First lets cast all timestamps to numerics:

```scala
val dfNum = df.withColumn("ts", $"timestamp".cast("long"))
```

Next lets find minimum timestamp over all rows:

```scala
val offset = dfNum.agg(min($"ts")).first.getLong(0)
```

and use it to compute groups:

```scala
val aDay = lit(60 * 60 * 24)
val group = (($"ts" - lit(offset)) / aDay).cast("long")
val dfWithGroups = dfNum.withColumn("group", group)
```

Finally you can use it as a grouping column:

```scala
dfWithGroups.groupBy($"group").agg(min($"value")).
```

If you want meaningful intervals (interpretable as timestamps) just multiply groups by `aDay`.

Obviously this won't handle complex cases like handling daylight saving time or leap seconds but should be good enough most of the time. If you need to handle properly any of this you use a similar logic using Joda time with an UDF.

Comment: What does the lit() do? and why do you need to convert a constant value to a lit?

Comment: @Neel  I ran it without lit and saw no difference. I am wondering what value needs to be